# Need Regex to match [#URL^Url Description^#]

Tags: c#, regex

```
I need regex to find this text
```

> [#URL^Url Description^#]

in a string and replace it with

> `<a href="some link">Url Description</a>`

"Url Description" can be set of characters in any language.

Any Regex Experts out there to help me?

Thanks.

Comment: It's not a question. Adding `?` to the end of sentence won't help.

Comment: That's nice. Have you tried yourself?

Comment: I tried myself with http://regexpal.com/ and with similar stackoverflow answers, but I am not able to get it exactly right. The URL description can be any language. As of now I need to test French and German. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

It might be a bit confusing, but you can use the following:

```
string str = @"[#URL^Url Description^#]";
var regex = new Regex(@"^[^^]+\^([^^]+)\^[^^]+$");
var result = regex.Replace(str, @"<a href=""some link"">$1</a>");
```

The first `^` means the beginning of the string;
The `[^^]+` means anything not a caret character;
The `\^` is a literal caret;
The `$` is the end of the string.

Basically, it captures all characters between the carets (`^`) and replace this in between the `<a>` tags.

See [ideone demo](http://ideone.com/xkA4hU).

You can also replace the last line with this:

```
var result = regex.Replace(str, @"<a href=""" + link + @""">$1</a>");
```

Where `link` is the variable containing the link you want to replace in.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your effort and Nice Regex. I also learned about ideone. its working for English. But I must test it for all the languages. But I agree with elmugrat, string.replace logic will work very well with out testing for all languages and it is readable as well. For My Question, your answer is correct, but I go for the other solution in real time scenario. Thanks.

Comment: @suresh2 Could you provide an example of non english description?

Comment: As of now, the url Description can be any English, German, French Characters. In the future it may be Chinese, Arabic or any language. I am not sure how the regex will work with all the unicode characters. I just used the string.replace, because I am confident that will work with all scenarios and the code is readable too. Thanks.

Comment: @suresh2 Oh if that's that, the regex works for all characters. See a japanese one I made [here](http://ideone.com/fWE35G).

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use `String.Replace()`?  A regex would work, but it looks like the format is well defined and regexes are harder to read.

```
string url = "[#URL^blah^#]";

string url_html = url.Replace("[#URL^", "<a href=\"http://www.somewhere.net\">")
                     .Replace("^#]", "</a>");
```

Comment: I can replace the URL with variables. @elmugrat I agree with you. I used string.replace instead of regex which is simple and better solution. When ever I see a string, Brain always think about Regex. :-). Thanks for the simple and better solution.